# openerp page numbers

Tags: odoo

I have tried to add page numbers in my document using the following two ways

I just want default page 1, page 2 etc.

1)

```
<para>
<drawCentredString x="18.5cm" y="1.5cm"> Page: <pageNumber/></drawCentredString></para>
```

2)

```
<para><drawCentredString x="18.5cm" y="1.5cm"> Page: <pageCount/></drawCentredString></para>
```

for option 2, I changed the pagecount class in trml2pdf.py as below

```
class PageCount(platypus.Flowable):
    def draw(self):
        self.canv.beginForm("pageCount")
        self.canv.setFont("Helvetica", utils.unit_get(str(8)))
##        self.canv.drawString(0, 0, str(self.canv.getPageNumber()))
        self.canv.drawString(0, 0, str(self.canv._pageCount))
        self.canv.endForm()

class PageReset(platypus.Flowable):
    def draw(self):
        self.canv._pageNumber = 0
```

--

No Luck !! I just get page :  or  or
error

Thanks in advance,Usha

Answer (score 0):

For the report with header = internal , you will have the 1/2 style page Count in report automatically . 
as in report of openerp it is using Numbered canvasing for the internal Heard report .

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by just writing "< pageNumber/>" in your .rml, but you have to write it under "template/paggeTemplate/pageGraphics" tags.

For example:

```
<template pageSize="(595.0,842.0)" title="Test" author="Martin Simon" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate>
        <pageGraphics>
            <drawCentredString x="10.5cm" y="0.8cm">Page: <pageNumber/></drawCentredString>
        </pageGraphics>
    </pageTemplate>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Arya, It took me long time to figure out that, drawCentredString has to be inside pageGraphics and whole thing inside pageTemplate.. I want to know can I put section inside a story ? can you share your gmail id ?

Comment: there are lots of examples in addons regarding section.